# Ansible role assert fails on vars built on count of hosts in inventory groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,
Using roles not directly playbook. 
I am trying count the number of hosts in inventory under certain groups and then assert that value. but am getting undefined value response in output. Also, is there any better way to do this?

```
      - name: "Ensure KUBECONFIG"
        shell: echo $KUBECONFIG
        register: kubeconfig_exists
        failed_when: kubeconfig_exists.rc != 0
      - debug:
          var: kubeconfig_exists.stdout_lines

      - name: "Find $PATH where Ansible looks for binaries on target system"
        register: echo_path
        shell: echo $PATH
      - debug:
          var: echo_path.stdout_lines

      - debug:
        vars:
            gpu_count: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
            cpu_count: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
      - assert:
               that:
                  - "gpu_count | int <= 1"
                  - "cpu_count | int >= 1"
               msg: "Assure k8s_nodes are not empty"
```

output:

```
TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : Ensure KUBECONFIG] ************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : debug] ******************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : assert] ****************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'gpu_count | int <= 1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (gpu_count | int <= 1): 'gpu_count' is undefined"}
```

inventory.txt

```
target1 ansible_host='{{ target1_hostip }}' ansible_ssh_pass='{{ target1_pass }}'
[k8s_gpu_nodes]
host1
host2
[k8s_cpu_nodes]
host3
host4
```

Comment: `gpu_count` is defined in `vars` for an empty debug task (that should print "Hello World !" wich is not part of your output). It is not defined in the `assert` task that follows. Hence it is undefined which is perfectly coherent with the error message you are getting.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the output. so how to fix this?

Comment: Well I already told you in my comment above: declare the vars in the correct task (and remove the unused one).

Comment: {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'k8s-gpu-nodes'

he offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - assert:\n        ^ here\n"}
      - assert:
          vars:
            gpu_count: "{{ groups['k8s-gpu-nodes'] | length }}"
          that:
                - "gpu_count | int >= 1"
          msg: "Assure k8s-nodes are not empty"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a playbook with the single needed task corrected:

```
---
- name: Check nodes in groups
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Check everything is ok
      vars:
        gpu_count: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
        cpu_count: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
      assert:
        that:
          - gpu_count | int > 0
          - cpu_count | int > 0
        msg: "Assure k8s_nodes are not empty"
```

When I play this playbook using your above inventory, here is the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/hosts.ini playbook.yml

PLAY [Check nodes in groups] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check everything is ok] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I think my challenge is to run from role. I am running within role not directly playbook and may be that is why am hitting issues? But reason?

Comment: I can put that task in a role if you want and run it with the exact same command, the result will be exactly the same. Your challenge is probably more in the fact that, in the last error message your posted you use dashes as separators for the group name rather than underscores IMO. `k8s-gpu-nodes => k8s_gpu_nodes`

Comment: yes changed the separators. thanks. but i get same error when i copied your task as is in role. 
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <type 'bool'>

The error appears to be in '/home/dtlu/ansible/roles/3_validations_on_ssh/tasks/main.yaml': line 29, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


      - name: Check nodes in groups
        ^ here

Comment: The error is somewhere else in your role / playbook, probably on the lines above. Please validate your files with yamllint and ansible-lint before your post. And when you try to fix a problem, work on an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing only that piece of problem, not a bunch of others.

Comment: I just created a test role with just this one task above and nothing else. error is same. test_role/tasks/main.yaml': line 1, column 9 
- name: Check nodes in groups
        ^ here

Comment: Posted my comments on github. Please check.

Comment: No I am not going to check because I already did. I already provided a solution (actually two) and spent more than enough time on this. You need to get a better understanding of the concept arround ansible (yaml, playbook, roles, etc...) and you will be able to figure out what is wrong on your side. Good luck in your learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to achieve this from within the role itself by declaring vars and counting its length

```
  - name: Assert local inventory if node groups are empty Master, etcd, cpu, apilb, mon, gpu
    assert:
      that:
        - "master_count | int > 0"
        - "gpu_count | int > 0"

      msg: "Assure k8s-nodes groups are not empty"
    vars:
      master_count: "{{ groups['kube-master'] | length }}"
      gpu_count: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] | length }}"
    ignore_errors: no
```